# Rpi is not booting up

Tags: pi-2

My RPi's SD card broke, so I tried inserting an SD card from the new RPi3 I had bought, but even then, the green light on the RPi remained on and steady. Apparently, this is a sign of the RPi not booting up. How can I fix this?
class 10 16 GB SD card

Answer (score 3):

You do not say what is the model of the RPi with broken card, but I am assuming something previous to RPi3.

I have not had any problems with the RPi3 not being able to physically read the same SD cards I use with RPi2, HOWEVER, the boot code on the card could be different if the Pi uses a previous generation chip. They may not boot using the same code. I spent a really long night learning this lesson one time.

Refer: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/16982376-updating-raspbian-on-your-microsd-for-the-raspberry-pi-2

Wikipedia has is a nice [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Processor) of different models and processors.

If I were you I would reimage my SD card with a fresh OS and give it another try in RPi3.

Comment: Are you saying older RPis cannot boot from an RPi3 card? AFAIK that's not true.

Comment: I'm trying to recall the exact combination that gave me a problem - might have been the difference between an RPi1 model B+ and an RPi2 model B because I remember using the mSDHC cards. In any case, I think if the CPU changes that you could have this problem - that's why I linked to the chart.